# How can I create an auto generated column that always has its default value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a MySQL column that always uses its default value and won't allow the user to insert values in it.

It's a creation_date column and I've set its default value to now(), but the user can insert any date value in this column if he wants to. The now() is only used if the user don't provide any values for that column.

I can imagine a few ways to accomplish my goal using triggers, but, is this the right way?

Isn't there a "protected" flag to set on the column or something like that?

Comment: What about `CREATE TABLE table_name( ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT    ............ );` What you tried before? Please show source examples

Comment: this 'user' you talk about, is this database user or end-user (customer)? if end-user and assuming the fields in table are: `creation_date, transaction_no, customer_id, staff_id`, what about provided them with query excluding 'creation_date' column `insert into table_name (transaction_no, customer_id, staff_id)`. this way the 'creation_date' wont get filled

Comment: just use a trigger

Comment: In the table structure set default value for the column `creation_date`. Then in insert query don't set any value for creation_date like skip that column in the query. This will not allow the user to set any value for that column and it will only pertain to your default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "protected" column concept, no.  You would need to use triggers.